# How to tell Google that I have changed my website URLs?

Tags: google, php, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I have done major updates to my website, and renamed all my URLs.

How can I tell Google that I have renamed these URLs and let Google refresh its index?

**My website URL**: `http://www.pndmasr.com/`

**My sitemap**: `http://www.pndmasr.com/sitemap.xml`

I have uploaded my sitemap via Google Webmaster Tools many times.

However, every time I search Google for "pndmasr", I still get results with old pages. I have waited more than 3 days but the problem remains. Any suggestions?

Is there a problem with my sitemap?

Comment: What about mod_rewrite to create a 301 redirect to the new urls? For arbitrary URLs, this doesn't work of course.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I changed the whole design and made new sitemap.xml and submited it on Google webmaster tool, tested it - it is OK. Ma site is on the 1st page of google results as before and I have new meta description below the site url on result page.
In cache however is the old site, and in Google webmaster tools I can see that I have so many crawling errors and all of them are connected with old urls and old sitemap which don't even exist? Same problem with one other site (separated account on webmaster tools). Any idea?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Do [301 redirects](http://www.tamingthebeast.net/articles3/spiders-301-redirect.htm) from the old URLs to the new URLs. This will tell the search engines and users that the pages have moved and where they are now. This also associates the old URL with the new URL for Google which means all of your old incoming links will now be associated with your new pages.
2. Submit an [XML sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/) in [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en)
3. Make sure you have an HTML sitemap. This is good for users and search engines.

Answer (score 7):

Ensure you have 301 redirects setup from old pages to the new ones! :)

Comment: That's a must, even if one wouldn't care about google. Dead links are evil.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to force Google to crawl your site. You just have to wait for the spider to crawl and reindex. If you submitted a sitemap on Webmaster Tools, that's about all you can do. It will probably take more than three days though.

Answer (score 0):

Sitemaps normally takes a few days to update, but 3 days is a bit much. Are you sure that you are not violating any of the [technical guidelines](https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769#2)? If you have too much javascript or flash google won't be able to crawl the site properly

Answer (score 0):

You can register your Site at Google's Webmaster Tools. There you can tell Google if a page of yours changed. Of course it takes a while until Google updates its search result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Webmaster Tools to remove the previous URLs from results. Go to `Site Configuration -> Crawler Access -> Remove URL`.

I was having the same problem as you. I had uploaded the new sitemap but the Google results still showed the old pages weeks afterwards. I used the "Remove URL" tool on all of the old URLs, and by the next morning a Google search only showed the new pages.