# Old content, new URL's, how to keep the old URL's still working? 301 redirects?

Tags: url, hyperlink, search-engines

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tell google that i have changed my website urls?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15688/how-to-tell-google-that-i-have-changed-my-website-urls)

I don;t know how to ask the question but situation is this. I have the old site with a lot of content that has recently been improved, built with another technology, among other things all the URL's have been coded in a nicer way.

**Old site:**

```
example.com/1/4444/p23a.php
```

**New site:**

```
example.com/music/rock
```

The problem is that Google and other search engines already cached a lot of this content and is appearing pretty high up. If I just redeploy the site with new links, I'm afraid all the search results will be invalid. Is there a way to solve this? All pages are dynamic, so I can't go and do any batch renaming or inserting redirect code. Also, I would eventually like for the old links to phase out, but not that people get broken links in Google search.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apache server, use .htacess redirection for your old URL's

In the htaccess file

```
RewriteRule OLD_URL NEW_URL [R=301,L]
```

By doing this, even if anyone hits your OLD URL he will be redirected ot your new URL and it is search engine optimized.

Comment: But all my links are dynamic. I don't even know how many are there nor how they look. Also, will the old ones eventually phase out from search results?

Comment: If your new dynamic links follow a pattern, then you can use wildcards while specifying the redirection in htaccess, for example : example.com/1/4444/* to redirect to example.com/music/rock