# how to remove the old urls from google search and replace new urls?

Tags: google, google-search-console, url

I know this question has been asked [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15688/how-to-tell-google-that-i-have-changed-my-website-urls), and [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8487/how-to-remove-urls-from-google-search-engine) before ,

But I have problem with  answers, so here is mine :

I have changed my urls structure ( not my domain ), and I want  google to **remove** the old urls and replace the new ones, and  I can't make redirection because I dont know what is it exactly ( its very dynamic ), How can I do this ?

Comment: Google will automatically crawl all your new URL's when they revisit your site. You can speed up the removal of old URL's by using the Remove URL option in Google Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 2):

If you can catch them, and you can find a matching new result, I suggest you header like this (in php, maybe you want something else):

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: /new_location_here");
```

That way, if you have `/some/TESTPAGE` with some PR value, and you link it to `/new/TESTPAGE` via a 301, you move the PR value with it, instead of loosing it.

If you can't find the new page, and they get on your site, send a 404:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
// You can add a default "not found page", or simply exit.
```

This will not preserve PR value. *You kinda allready should have the 404 method though, this is good for SEO (all the not found pages will be duplicate content otherwise).*